# Cannot access the $rootscope properties in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

In may application i have build a login page and after successfully login in the system the user is redirected to another page using the javascript function.

```
window.location.href = '/index.html';
```

Both the login page and index page using same controller.During redirecting to login page.
 I have set the properties of `$rootScope` obect using the below lines in the button click event.

```
$rootScope.curusername = $scope.username;
$rootScope.password = $scope.password;
window.location.href = '/index.html';
```

Now I want to access the username and password in the redirected page using the below syntax

logeed in name : {{curusername}}  but no value is showing. Where is my fault.

Thanks and Regards
Utpal Maity

Comment: as soon as the route changes to '/index.html', then the controller is reinitialized. so the {{curusername}} will be undefined or null

Comment: @Techno Sawy Ok so how can I handle the situation.Please suggesr.

Comment: Why do you have to perform the redirect?

Comment: Because that is the way I want to perform login functionality in my application.First a login pagewill appear and after that all other page will appear.And all the page will deal with the same controller.

Comment: I have find a way out for this. i am storing the values in the cookies and I am able to retrieve them and assign them in a scope variable by using this logic written in a function.                                 $scope.username = $cookieStore.get("username");   but the problem is that how can I call this function on the loading of the view. because I have tested it by applying the function on a button click event and it is working fine but I got stuck in the load event.

Comment: A better approach will be that you make use of a service. In this service you store your user information.

If you have a full SPA it's also better to use the $location provider for redirecting: http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services.$location

Comment: Hi i have tried this but not successfull.myapp.factory('UserService', [function () {
    var User = {
        username: '',
        password: '',

        login: function (username, password) {
            username = username;
            password = password;
    }
    };
    
    return User;
}]);

Comment: @Dieter Goetelen I have tried the solution using service as said my you but first time it is loading after the page refesh it is not working. I have gave more details about it in the following  link olease have a look and tell me where I am making the mistake.                       https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/angular/u_HIMJOXRJs